# How to get entry permit for protected areas in India?

Tags: visas, india, permits

India has many [protected areas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreigners_(Protected_Areas)_Order_1958_(India)). On the e-Tourist visa I didn't see anywhere an option to include protected areas in my visa and my visa confirmation explicitly states:

> e-Tourist Visa (eTV) once issued on arrival is Only Single Entry,
>   non-extendable , non-convertible & **not valid for visiting
>   Protected/Restricted and Cantonment Areas**.

How do I get a permit to enter protected areas?

Comment: If you are abroad you can contact Indian embassy and they are authorised to issue the permit. However there are many restrictions for such a permit. [Ministry of North East development](http://mdoner.gov.in/content/rappap-restrictedprotected-area-permit) has a page for north east indian restricted areas

Comment: Also [this pdf](http://mha1.nic.in/pdfs/ForeigD-FAQs-onPAPandRAP.pdf) from home ministry, India has additional info on protected area permit and restriction on the same

Comment: On a visit in 2010 I took a road trip from Kalimpong to Gangtok, Sikkim with 4 others, 3 of whom were (or could pass for) Indian residents. For the remaining pair of us the procedure at the Sikkim border was, walk up the road a bit and buy a tourist permit, then walk back down the road with said permit and trade it, with some more money, for a passport stamp. A bit past Gangtok we saw a booth on a road that I think went to the China border with 2 guys who looked very alert when they saw me, but we turned off to a shrine just when we got to them.

Comment: bcmtouring.com is a very active forum for bike car motor travelling in india, especially Leh, and other restricted areas. In leh Indians also need some permit for some areas around, try asking question there, or look in already answered posts. I am no affili with them except a simple user.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Originally your question was about [wildlife protected areas](http://www.wiienvis.nic.in/Database/Protected_Area_854.aspx). Such areas in India are designated as Wildlife sanctuaries or National parks. These areas, while out of bound for habitation or economic activity, are very much open to foreign and Indian visitors to explore and watch wild animals in their natural surroundings. The entry rules for these parks are drafted by respective managements and while they may have restrictions on the number of people allowed or the kind of equipment you can bring, you can just walk to the ticket counter and buy a ticket (although for foreigners prices are generally 6-10 times higher than for Indians).

- If you wish to watch Asiatic lions at [Gir National Park](http://girlion.in/ForestVisitDetails.aspx), you can buy a "permit" for a safari online.
- [Kanha National park](http://www.kanhavillage.com/kanha_national_park/information---kanha-national-park) also only stipulates that foreign visitors have to pay double the fee.

If you wish to visit wildlife sanctuaries or national parks, I suggest booking a resort which is near such a place and then the resort managemet will be able to provide you with information about any additional documentation/restrictions which may be in place. But. generally they are open for all.

**The *other* protected areas**

Certain areas near India's external borders have been notified as [Restricted or Protected Areas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreigners_%28Protected_Areas%29_Order_1958_%28India%29) (The edited link in your question) for security reasons. Foreign national and, in some areas, Indians who are not residents of such areas need a special permit from the Home Ministry (Which deals with Internal Security in India) to visit such areas.

Depending on whether the area is a Restricted Area or Protected Area, you need a Restricted Area Permit (RAP) or Protected Area Permit (PAP).

Why would someone want to visit such areas? Because these areas have gems such as

- [Leh](http://www.gettyimages.in/detail/photo/village-in-leh-ladakh-india-high-res-stock-photography/103000952)
- [Spiti Valley](http://www.gettyimages.in/detail/photo/spiti-valley-royalty-free-image/143672605)
- [Havelock Islands](http://www.gettyimages.in/detail/photo/govindnagar-beach-havelock-royalty-free-image/165307034)
- [Nathu La](http://www.gettyimages.in/detail/photo/panoramic-view-of-tsongmo-lake-royalty-free-image/536230409) etc.

[This FAQ](http://mha1.nic.in/pdfs/ForeigD-FAQs-onPAPandRAP.pdf) issued by Ministry of Home Affairs answers most of questions about RAP and PAP. Quote:

> Under  the  Foreigners  (Protected  Areas)  Order,  1958,  all  areas  falling  between  the  ‘Inner  line’,  as  defined  in  the  said  order,  and  the  International  Border  of  the  State  have  been  declared  as  a  Protected   Area.   Currently,   Protected   Areas   are   located   in   he   following States: -
>
> (i) Whole of Arunachal Pradesh
> (ii) Parts of Himachal Pradesh
> (iii) Parts of Jammu & Kashmir
> iv) Whole   of   Manipur
> (v)    Whole    of    Mizoram
> (vi)   Whole   of   Nagaland
> (vii)  Parts  of  Rajasthan
> (viii)  Whole  of  Sikkim  (partly  in  Protected  Area  and  partly  in  Restricted Area)
> (ix)   Parts   of   Uttarakhand

MHA has **delegated powers to various authorities to issue requisite permits** to foreign visitors. The authorities who can grant such permits varies for each region. You can get in touch with local Indian mission to find if they have the power to issue such permits for the areas you wish to travel. A full list of authorities for each place is on [immihelp](http://www.immihelp.com/nri/protected-restricted-area-permit-india.html). For some states such information is also provided on respective tourism websites:

- For [Sikkim](http://sikkimtourism.gov.in/webforms/general/pdf/RAP.pdf), you may obtain the permit from Indian missions abroad.
- For [Andaman & Nicobar Islands](http://www.andamans.gov.in/html/entryformality.html) too you can obtain the permit from abroad or on arrival by air at Port Blair.
- For [Leh and Ladakh](http://www.lahdclehpermit.in/pap.pdf) permits are issued only by District authorities at Leh and the conditions are more stringent.

Generally applications for PAP must be made in groups(2-4), with an authorized guide and pre-defined itinerary (Source from [Leh PDF](http://www.lahdclehpermit.in/pap.pdf). However, if you are a citizen of China, Pakistan, Afghanistan, or are of such origin, or a solo traveller, your case will be referred to MHA and may take significantly longer. Source: From MHA FAQs

> In  all  cases  relating  to  grant  of  PAP/RAP  for  an  individual
> foreign tourist, the proposal would require prior clearance from the
> ministry of Home Affairs.  The requisite clearance would be conveyed
> by MHA only on the basis of the recommendation of the State Government
> concerned.

AND

> With  a  view  to  promote  tourism,  some  areas  (notified  by  the
> Government  of  India  from  time  to  time)  can  be  visited  by
> foreign  tourists, either in groups, or as a couple in the case of a
> husband and wife, or by individuals, after obtaining the necessary
> permit from the competent  authority.    Necessary  powers  have  been
> delegated  to  various  authorities  to  issue  the  special  permit,
> without  the  prior  approval  of  the  Ministry  of  Home  Affairs,
> to  facilitate  foreign  tourists  subject to the following
> exceptions:
>
> (i)  Special  instructions  applicable  to  foreign diplomats  and  members    of    the    United    Nations    and  International    Organisations  holding  Diplomatic  /  Official Passport  are  issued by the Ministry of External Affairs.
>
> (ii) Citizens  of  Afghanistan,  China  and  Pakistan  and  foreign nationals  of  Pakistani  origin,  shall  not  be  issued  a  special permit  without  the  prior  approval  of  the  Ministry  of  Home Affairs.

Comment: To be clear, a foreigner visiting most of Sikkim requires a RAP which is also available on arrival; I got mine in Rangpo. A tour doesn't seem to be required. The protected areas are near borders, and I think a PAP for the particular place you are going must be obtained inside Sikkim, usually at the police checkpoint you'll pass on the way there. These may require foreigners to have a tour guide. I don't think foreigners can go to Nathu La at all, that is the China border post I was on the road to.

Comment: The link @RedBaron gave for Sikkim lists places that the PAP can be acquired within India as well: it's not required to get it only from missions abroad.